# How can I bubble errors on Promises without calling `catch` at every level?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm struggling to figure out how to *properly* bubble errors with promises.

Specifically, what I'm talking about is a situation where there is *nested promises*. I want to be able to *implictly* pass the `resolve` and `reject` functions to the nested promise.

It'll be more obvious what I mean by showing some code.

The following is what I have been using successfully:

```
var asyncIsEven = function(number) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      if (number % 2 == 0) { return resolve(number) }
      else { return reject("number is odd") }
  })
}

var A = function (number) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    return asyncIsEven(number).then(resolve).catch(reject)
  })
}
```

Here, it seems pretty unnecessary to write `then(resolve).catch(reject)`. 
I understand that I can just make function `A` return `asyncIsEven(number)`, but there are situations when I want to provide a `then` function but have no need to provide a `catch` function (or vice versa).

What I've tried:

**this works, but is not really what I want because I'm not providing a `then` handler to the nested callback**

```
var A = function (number) {
  return Promise.all([asyncIsEven(number)])
}

// or alternatively
var A = function(number) {
  return asyncIsEven(number)
}
```

**This is what I want to write, but it doesn't work**

```
var A = function(number) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    return asyncIsEven(number).then(resolve)
  })
}
```

When I say it "doesnt work", what I mean is that I cannot write the following:

```
A(2).then(function(number) {
  console.log(`${number} is even`)
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

Because the `catch` function will never be called.

In other words - if I define function `A` to return `asyncIsEven(number).then(resolve)`, how can I bubble errors from `asyncIsEven` up to the `reject` callback given to `A`?

Comment: `A(3).then(function(number) {
  console.log(`${number} is even`)
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})` will take you in `catch-block`

Comment: What you want to write always resolves, it never rejects, hence an error is never thrown from the `A()` method, so you simply can't write it like that, you have to reject if there is an error? On the other hand, the `A()` function seems superfluous

Comment: If you find yourself using `new Promise` for anything other that wrapping a callback-based function call, you are almost always using `new Promise` in a place where you shouldn't. It'd a good way to accidentally discard errors like this. I don't understand why your first example isn't what you want, if you give more info that might make this easier to answer.

Comment: @adeneo this is not "practical" code, I just devised it to explain the conceptual issue. Providing `A(3)` with that definition of `A` will not call the `catch` method. Anyway, I think I figured it out, and I'm posting an answer.

Comment: I understand that it's not "practical", the practical thing to do inside `A()` would be just `return asyncIsEven(number)`, or even just call that function directly without another wrapper. If you want to wrap in a new Promise, you have to somehow both resolve and reject depending on the outcome.

Comment: "*I understand that I can just make function A `return asyncIsEven(number)`, but there are situations when I want to provide a `then` function*" - please show us such an example of such a situtation. You still can simply `return` that promise. For your case (that you "want to write but doesn't work") you really can use `var A = asyncIsEven` (or the longer `function A(number) { return asyncIsEven(number); }`) and it *will* work. There doesn't seem to be any need to nest promises - and certainly you never have to call them from inside the `Promise` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In response to comments and the duplicate question, I can write the following answer:

Wrapping `A`'s return value (or that of any function which returns a different Promise) with `new Promise()` or `Promise.all` is unnecessary.

Instead, just call `return otherPromise().then(handler)` and the `reject` function on `otherPromise` can be used with `A().catch(handler)`.

When `new Promise()` is used to wrap this return value, the `reject` function on the inner promise will *not* bubble to `A().catch()`. However, using `Promise.all` to wrap the return value *will* bubble up the error.

Comment: But you still can't write `A(2).then( (number) => console.log(number))` because `number` would now be an array, exactly the same as the example in your question using `Promise.all` ?